# Is there a way to compare game prices in different stores?

Tags: steam, humble-bundle

Sometimes I get games a bit cheaper on Humble Store or Fanatical, but I wonder: is there's a way to see if it's even cheaper somewhere else?

Comment: Before going shopping, I recommend you familiarize yourself with the unfortunate invention of *region-locked* keys. Cheaper will not always translate to *cheaper for you*.

Comment: @chebureki it's not an unfortunate invention, but the ability for retailers to set a price according to local earning power instead of universal foreign exchange conversion. $5 US is a week of food in some countries. It is a very complex global market problem that's pretty difficult to regulate.

Comment: Also, you should probably look into a site before throwing your money at it. Some have practices that you might not want to encourage. Some game devs did come out with a statement that 'they prefer you pirate their game than buy it from services like G2A' because those keys are usually gotten in crappy ways that hurt the devs. https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-48908726

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes! There are price comparison websites, for example [gg.deals](https://gg.deals/).
It sorts prices by best deal and tells you where to buy cheap Steam games. Note that it's not always a Steam key that you're buying, depends on the store. It also tells you if the game's available in some subsription based library or if it's even cheaper in keyshops, which you can turn off if you don't trust them. It also tracks the price history so you're always sure you're getting the best deal possible.

Comment: I hesitate to just drop a link here, but my personal favorite for comparison is isthereanydeal.com - it's got all the features I could ask for, including monitoring your various wishlists on Steam and other sites and generating a list of the best deals on just those games; but also things like "I only want Steam keys" or allowing you to ignore particular sites if you don't want to deal with them, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I use [IsThereAnyDeal](https://isthereanydeal.com/) for price comparisons of PC games. It lists the cheapest price currently available and the cheapest price a game has ever been. It also lists the price on multiple official storefronts.

[image: Is there any deal page for Dead Cells]

If you have the browser extension [Augmented Steam](https://augmentedsteam.com/), you can have this information displayed on the Steam page of any game.

[image]